# NSTextField subclass for sliding text - Objective-C/Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, subclass, nstextfield, ticker

I want to do what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290262/nstextfield-bounce-truncated-text-instead-of-wrapping). I know I am kinda repeating the question but that post does not have an answer. I have searched the net and didn't find anything I could understand either.

So, here is my problem: I want to create an NSTextField subclass that animates text (in the way described by the other post) when the text is too long to be completely displayed. I have absolutely no idea on how to do this, so some sample code would be nice for complicated answers. If it helps, I only want to use this to animate labels (text not selectable nor editable). Thanks.

Comment: You can take a look at [this SO entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232801/itunes-song-title-scrolling-in-cocoa). It is not based on a [NSTextField](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but on a [NSView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html), but the result is the same.

Comment: @LaurentEtiemble Awesome! That is exactly what I needed. All I need now is to modify the code a little bit and clean it. Please post as an answer so you can receive the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this [SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232801/itunes-song-title-scrolling-in-cocoa) is close to what you need. It is not based on a NSTextField but on a NSView, but the result is what you are looking for and it should note be hard to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Those links should show you the way :

[Making uitextview scroll programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266766/how-can-i-make-scroll-a-uitextview-programatically)

[Auto Scrolling UITextView Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229197/auto-scrolling-uitextview-problem)

They talk about iPhone classes, but I'm sure you will be able to adapt them for NSTextField.